# Basic Question about Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, normalization

I have a basic question about quantum mechanics. Let's say we consider one particle in one space dimension. In my understanding, in quantum mechanics, the location is given by a distribution function $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Now, the operator for measuring the location is the operator $A: \mathcal{D}(A) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $\varphi \mapsto x\varphi$. If we want to calculate the expected outcome of a measurement, we have to calculate $\langle \psi , A \psi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi^2(x) x \mathrm{d}x$. However, in case we choose 
\begin{equation}
\psi= \begin{cases} \frac12,\quad x\in [ 0,2]\\ 0,\quad \text{ else,} \end{cases}
\end{equation}
we obtain $\langle \psi , A \psi \rangle = \frac12$, which is not the average location of the particle. So where did I misunderstand something?

Any help is muchly appreciated!

Comment: In terms of books, I recommend R. Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: Hint: Check the $L_2$-norm of $\psi$.

Comment: In other words: Is your wavefunction normalized?

Comment: Ah, so the value has to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ instead of $\frac12$. Otherwise, what I wrote was correct?

Comment: Yes. Does the integral  check with your answer?

Comment: Slightly unrelated but you need to be careful: $\phi \mapsto x\phi$ is not a map $L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Consider $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos: Yes, now I get the correct result. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MarcusAurelius I observed that problem. That's why I wrote $A:\mathcal{D}(A) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$. How do you properly define the spaces and the position operator in this example?